# how to edit own item in listview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listview, edit, comments

I want to implement a comment list and use list view to binding data. But now I have a problem that, only specific item can be deleted or edited by owner. how to config list view to do this function, thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to databind a listview?  Or maybe you're looking to edit/delete multiple records *at the same time*?

Answer (score 0):

Once the list is bound (like in OnDataBound event), iterate through the items, and use logic similar to this:

```
foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
{
    btnDelete.Enabled = User.UserID == ListView1.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex]["UserID"];
}
```